# How to get the nearest ancestor node based on multiple value

Tags: xml, xslt

How could I get the nearest ancestor based on multiple choice nodes ?
 
What I mean:
Let's assume  I have a lot of tags in my XML file : *chapter*, *section*, *subsection*,  *subsubsection*, *abstract* and others. Let's assume that I am on a node on a level and I want to see which node is the nearest from me based one the choices I have (*chapter*,*section*,*subsection*,*subsubsection*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ancestor::*[self::chapter | self:section | self::subsection | self::subsubsection][1]`.

If you want the name then use `name(ancestor::*[self::chapter | self:section | self::subsection | self::subsubsection][1])`.

Comment: And if i wanna get the tag name not the entire content only the tag name

Comment: god damn, that's what i was looking for ! lol But couldn't do it with the name. Thank you !

Comment: And if my chapter have a title and wanna the content of that title how could i do that ?

Comment: That sounds like a new question you should raise together with a sample of your XML, currently we don't know whether the `title` is an attribute (`ancestor::*[self::chapter | self:section | self::subsection | self::subsubsection][1]/@title`) or a child element `ancestor::*[self::chapter | self:section | self::subsection | self::subsubsection][1]/title`).

Comment: its not an attribute it's a child for chapter or section or subsection or subsubsection

Comment: But abstract doesn't have, so that's my problem. maybe i should ask a question

Answer (score 0):

Document order places children after their parents so

```
(ancestor::chapter | ancestor::section | ..... )[last()]
```

should give you what you need.

When you apply predicates to an `ancestor::` location step the nodes are numbered in reverse order, with `[1]` being the nearest ancestor and. `[last()]` being the most distant. But when you apply predicates to a parenthesised expression like this the count is in normal document order regardless of the axes used inside the expression.

Comment: but this get the entire content right ? if i wanna just the name of the tag ?

Comment: @Damiii this XPath will get you a reference to the node, if you want its name you can use the normal `name(...)` or `local-name(...)` functions as appropriate.